# What is the 'invalid argument' in my list.add

Tags: c#, .net, list, csv

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("d:\\DK\\DK_CSV.csv"));
List<Csv> CsvList = new List<Csv>();

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    CsvList.Add(values[0]);
}
```

Just playing with a Monkey Sort.  I was able to ReadallLines from CSV into a Datatable no problem from a CSV but I decided I wanted to try to using streamreader instead and just dump the CSV contents into a List I created.  Im getting this error though.  Any idea why??

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match >for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(MonkeySort.Csv)' has >some invalid arguments C:\Users\514653\Documents\Visual Studio 2013>\Projects\MonkeySort\MonkeySort\Program.cs 43  21  MonkeySort

****Works now.  Here is the corrected coded. Thanks Joe!!****

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("d:\\DK\\DK_CSV.csv"));
            List<Csv> CsvList = new List<Csv>();
            Csv _Csv = new Csv();
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                CsvList.Add(new Csv()
                    {
                        Position = values[0],
                        Name = values[1]
                    });

            }
            foreach(var item in CsvList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Position + item.Name);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: You have declared a `List<Csv>` but you are adding a string to that list. Of course the two (Csv and string) are not the same. Please show how is defined your Csv class

Comment: You're adding a string to a List<Csv>

Comment: namespace MonkeySort
    {
        public class Csv
        {
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
            }
    }

Comment: After seeing yous Csv class...   To fully correct your problem, we need more info to re-write a portion of your code.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im just trying to import the contents of a CSV file into a List<customClass>.  I have already done it using a datatable but then im dumping it into a List<customClass> from there so I figured why go through the datatable at all.  Just put it in the List<customClass> to begin with.  Im really just trying to get better with using List<customClass> stuff.  Pretty new to programming.

Comment: I think what you suggested may work.  Im messing with it now. I will get back to you.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

values[0] is of type string

CsvList is of type `List<Csv>`.

You can only add objects of type Csv to a `List<Csv>`.

You can not add a string to a list of type `List<Csv>` unless you convert it to a Csv object first.

EDIT:

use this, instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count(); i++)
     CsvList.Add(
          new Csv()
          {
               Position = i.ToString(),
               Name = values[i]
          });
```

right now, it looks like you might be missing a Value field in your Csv object?  What is name?  Is it the column heading?  What is Position?  Is it the column number?

Comment: Thanks Joe, I needed to instantiate the class custom CSV class.  I wouldn't have known to do that.

Comment: Random nitpick: If `Csv` defines an implicit conversion from `string`, then it works as well. But obviously that's not the case here and OP probably doesn't even know those exist.

Comment: Joey are you saying to use a constructor in Csv to do the conversion?

Comment: @Puerto - That's one way to do it, but I'm guessing Joey was talking about this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28VS.71%29.aspx    this way, so can say stuff like:  Csv myCsvObject = values;  and if you set it up correctly, behind the scenes it'll convert string[] to a Csv object.